# Downgrade Magento version 2.4.1 to 1.9.4? Need complete steps

Tags: php, magento

I've already looked at below solution on stackoverflow. However, I need complete steps as the below solution mention that "Then run all the commands upgrade/static content deploy / di compilation and clear cache" - which I don't know and the reason is I am new to magento.

[Magento downgrade 2.4.2 to 2.3.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294381/how-to-downgrade-magento-2-3-3-to-magento-2-3-1-or-2-3-2)

Also, the above solution doesn't mention anything about 2.4.2 to 1.9.x which I am looking for.

Can someone please guide me what sorts of other commands I've to apply and what I've to prepare before doing this downgrade?

Lot of people on the net have some sorts of answer but not complete answer. So this question will help those people too.

thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You'd do better to ask on [magento.se]

Comment: The only safe way to do this is to restore from a backup. Conceivably, the upgrade broke so much that it isn't working anymore, so nothing should be lost. No system, Windows, Mac, WordPress, Drupal, etc. has a downgrade option. They do have, however, a recommendation to backup before upgrading so that you can undo the upgrade. That's how all software works. You _could_ try a composer downgrade, which will just install different files, but it is a major version change so you should expect everything to break.

Comment: Why would you want to downgrade to version 1? It's not supported and maintained anymore. Would be better to fix any issues with 2.4.